# How can CQRS contribute to more scalable applications

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Lately I've been reading a lot on CQRS architecture. One of the foremost points stated on why one should use CQRS is scalability.

Now I don't quite understand how this can work.

Let's say you have your `typical` CQRS application design.

- Two Datastores
- One for the Command Side
- One for Query Side
- When a Command has been processed an Event is send which could update the second Datastore

It's often stated that having a datastore for querying and one for handling commands would make your application more scalable.
But how can this work if the second datastore that stores the event data needs to respond to the query requests and also constantly needs to update iteself based on the incoming events ?

Why not have one datastore where the commands are stored and where the query side can re-use the stored data for fetching it's result data ?

Answer (score 13):

You might find interesting to read this [old blog post](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/) from [Greg Young](https://twitter.com/gregyoung) himself, where he explains what exactly CQRS is.

CQRS is not about having 2 different stores, but, as stated on Greg's article:

> CQRS is simply the creation of two objects where there was previously
>   only one. The separation occurs based upon whether the methods are a
>   command or a query

What you describe here is more Event Sourcing.

Now back to your question: `How can CQRS contribute to more scalable applications?`
Greg answers that as well:

> CQRS allows to host two services differently eg: we can host the
>   read service on 25 servers and the write service on two. The
>   processing of commands and queries is fundamentally asymmetrical, and
>   scaling the services symmetrically does not make a lot of sense.

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Two Datastores
> One for the Command Side
> One for Query Side
> When a Command has been processed an Event is send which could update the second Datastore
> ```

This is CQRS with ES (event sourcing), don't confuse things!

Event sourcing is about storing domain events raised by handling the incoming commands. So you can play them back any time you want. This makes the read side more flexible, because you can any time change your read database structure, and after that you just replay the domain events instead of writing some fancy migration code. Storing the commands is not okay, because you don't necessarily have the same environment (for example different time on the server), so you cannot replay them safely. Command storing is just for logging purposes...

Command and Query responsibility segregation is about dividing the incoming requests into two groups: write (command) and read (query). The basic idea behind this was, that you don't have to use the same ORM entities by reading your relational database as you use by writing it. So you spare the object-relational mapping by the reads, which makes things faster. Later it went through an improvement, and now it means that you can use multiple databases by the read part, each one specific to a group of queries. For example, if a graph database, like neo4j fits better to some of the queries, then you add a neo4j database instead of using the same relational database to serve those queries. This can make things a lot faster...

Comment: _if a graph database, like neo4j fits better to some of the queries, then you add a neo4j database instead of using the same relational database to serve those queries. This can make things a lot faster..._  **So true!** as Greg Young said "Wrong models cause massive accidental complexity"

Comment: ES is not about storing events. It's about mutating an object state by applying events. And CQRS works great without ES.

Comment: @MikeSW "ES is not about storing events. It's about mutating an object state by applying events." - Actually you are wrong, I mean event sourcing is a storing mechanism, which works the way you and I both described using different words.
"And CQRS works great without ES." - nobody said otherwise.

Comment: "Aggregate roots that implement the EventSourcedAggregateRoot interface can be stored in an event sourcing repository. Those repositories do not store the aggregate itself, but the series of events generated by the aggregate. Based on these events, the state of an aggregate can be restored at any time." - from the [Manual of the Axon Framework](http://www.axonframework.org/docs/2.0/repositories-and-event-stores.html)

Comment: "Axon framework provides a few repository implementations that can use event sourcing as storage method for aggregates. These repositories require that aggregates implement the EventSourcedAggregateRoot interface. As with most interfaces in Axon, we also provide one or more abstract implementations to help you on your way. "